# Show a form by the string name without reflection

Tags: c#

I wonder if it is possible to display a form dynamically by name string without using reflection.

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: either reflection (`Type.GetType(string)`) or a big `switch` statement.

Comment: Why is reflection not an option for you?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Write a method that knows how to map the string name to an instance of that type. No reflection necessary. But that doesn't sound as dynamic as you might like. Explain what you might like, and you might get some good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, with a huge [`switch` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like this:

```
switch (formName)
{
    case "form1":
        new Form1().Show();
        break;
    ...
}
```

and the same `switch` statement would apply in a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

But it sure is a lot cleaner to do something more along the lines of:

```
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(formName));
```

By default the [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method performs a case-sensitive search, so if that doesn't work you can use a different overload [`Type.GetType(string, bool, bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a87che9d.aspx) in which you can determine if you want to ignore the case. It might look something like this:

```
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(formName, true, false));
```

Comment: my question is that with reflection are many lines that's all, just looking for a way to have less code.

Thanks michael a reply I clarified some doubts.

Comment: @MoisesReyes, generally speaking, you're going to have a lot more code when you're trying to break down a lot of types. Reflection allows you to do it with one line of code. Now, if you're trying to get at properties on those types and you know nothing about them that's completely different than building a type by its string (one liner as above).

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear. But is this what you're looking for:

```
if (form.Name == "name1") form.Show();
```